# mongodb aggregate count distinct field and group by another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have a data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ch_19yARNHDsLEzoG2t2hxHvpw3",
        "currency": "usd",
        "customer": "cus_1",
        "amount": 1200, 
    },{
        "id": "ch_19yASNHDsLEzoG2tfbFOFswm",
        "currency": "jpy",
        "customer": "cus_1",
        "amount": 1800, 
    },{
        "id": "ch_19yXtXHDsLEzoG2t7P5vTkoD",
        "currency": "php",
        "customer": "cus_2",
        "amount": 1500, 
    },{
        "id": "cus_Aa11MnL8d6Vui6",
        "currency": "usd",
        "customer": "cus_3",
        "amount": 2000, 
    },{
        "id": "cus_AXjwOn1zKAyIPN",
        "currency": "php",
        "customer": "cus_4",
        "amount": 500, 
    },
]
```

First, I want to get the total distinct customers. Then, I want to group the data by currency, get the sum and store it in a field as an array. Here's how would it look like.

```
{
    "total_customers": 4,
    "gross": [
        {
            "currency": "usd",
            amount: 3200
        },{
            "currency": "jpy",
            amount: 1800
        },{
            "currency": "php",
            amount: 2000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, probably you haму an error in your example, if you need to sum every amount per client per currency, then in "php" currency you should have 2000.

I believe there are lot of more elegant solutions to this task (probably it should be done in two queries, but if you want all in one), i can just share my quick one:

```
db.getCollection('trips').aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$customer", save:{$push:{currency:"$currency", amount:"$amount"}}}},
    { $group: { _id: null, count: {$sum:1}, save:{$push:"$save"}}},
    { $unwind : "$save" },
    { $unwind : "$save" },
    { $group: {_id:{currency:"$save.currency",total_customers:"$count"}, gross:{ $sum:"$save.amount"}}},
    { $group: {_id:"$_id.total_customers", gross:{ $push:{currency:"$_id.currency",amount:"$gross"}}}},
    { $project: {_id:0, total_customers:"$_id", gross:"$gross"}}
])
```

result:

```
{
    "gross" : [ 
        {
            "currency" : "jpy",
            "amount" : 1800
        }, 
        {
            "currency" : "usd",
            "amount" : 3200
        }, 
        {
            "currency" : "php",
            "amount" : 2000
        }
    ],
    "total_customers" : 4.0
}
```

P.S. i am not saying it the best/optimal one :)